# What is the difference between 'finished' and 'completed'?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between **'finished' and 'completed'**, as both words gives the same meaning?

> Ex 1: He **finished** his homework.
>
> Ex 2: He **completed** his homework.

And also how or where to use these words?

> Dictionary Reference:
>
> Completed: Finish making or doing.
>
> Finished: Brought to an end; completed.

As for me both sentences have the same meaning. So is there any real difference between them?

Comment: The words can have the exact same meaning, especially in the sentence you ask about.

Comment: When you marry a right woman you are complete.
When you marry a wrong woman you are finished.
When the right woman sees you with the wrong woman,
you are completely finished.

Comment: I think the two words (complete and finish) carry the same meaning

Comment: In most cases where *completed* is correct you could say *finished* instead, but the reverse is not true. *Finished [verb]ing* usually can't be changed to *completed [verb]ing*. Here are some examples that work only with *finish[ed]*: "Have you finished eating?" *"What time does your shift finish?"* "I've not finished exercising." *"You're finished."* "Finish up for now." (That last one means to stop doing something with the expectation of continuing later.)

Answer (score 5):

In many contexts, the meanings are pretty much the same, but you might hear *finished* more often than *completed* in casual conversation. For example:

> I've finished my shopping.
>   She finished the song.
>   He finished the race.

I could use *completed* in those sentences – the meaning wouldn't change, but the [register](https://drsaraheaton.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/) might sound off.

The word *completed* can convey some sense of accomplishment. In the context of a race, it might work when the race is a major achievement:

> He completed his first marathon last year.

Homework, though, is not really a major achievement, so I think you'd hear *finished* more often in casual conversation:

> “Joey, where are you going? Did you finish your homework?”

That said, you might see *completed* in more formal contexts, such as a paper on education, or a course syllabus:

> Students must complete six homework assignments during the semester.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a bit about the difference between *finish* and *complete*, in hope that it can help "complete" other answers, which are already good, a little. (In other words, I write this as a supplementary answer.)

The striking difference between the two can be observed in the contrast of *"You finish me"* and *"You complete me"*.

***"You finish me"*** (or *"You finish me off"*) means "You kill me", i.e. you put "the end" to my life.

***"You complete me"*** is normally used between couples, in the sense that one (e.g. a wife) completes the other (e.g. a husband). With her, he is a more "complete" person. Without her, he is "incomplete". A good example of this phrase can be found in *Jerry Maguire* (one of my favorite movies of all time!):

> Jerry Maguire: *[babbling and struggling]* I love you. You... you complete me. And I just...
>   Dorothy: Shut up,
>   *[pause]*
>   Dorothy: just shut up.
>   *[Pause]*
>   Dorothy: You had me at "hello". You had me at "hello".
>   <sub>Source: IMDb http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116695/quotes?item=qt0389299</sub>

So, once you *finish* me, my life is "no more".

But once you *complete* me, my life is "perfect".

Back to your homework sentence (*He completed/finished his homework*), homework is a kind of work. After work reaches its perfect state (i.e. "it's done"), we'll have no more of that work. This is why in the context of work, including your *homework*, saying either *He finished his homework* or *He completed his homework* will have pretty much the same meaning.

Comment: I think you're mixing apples and oranges here. The word _complete_ in "You complete me" has a different meaning than the word _complete_ in "Let's complete the homework assignment tomorrow." They are listed as meanings 8 & 9 in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/complete); one means "finish" while the other means "make more whole or prefect." Besides, everyone knows that "completed" homework assignments are rarely "perfect" assignments – that's why teachers carry red pens! ;^)

Answer (score 0):

From [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/finish) :

> **fin•ish** /ˈfɪnɪʃ/ v.
>
> > to bring or come to an end or to completion
> >
> > to use completely
> >
> > to overcome completely; destroy or kill
> >
> > to put a finish on (wood, metal, etc.)

And still from [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/complete) :

> **com•plete** /kəmˈplit/ v.
>
> > to make whole, entire, or perfect
> >
> > to bring to an end ;finish

We can see that *finish* and *complete* use each other to define themselves, so they have a **very close meaning**.

*Finish* has :

- the `killing` meaning,
- the `using the whole product` meaning
- and the `surface coating` meaning

in addition of the *complete* common meaning.

While *complete* has the extra `finishing perfectly` meaning.

---

> He finished his homework.

He simply ended it, did enought to consider it finished.

> He completed his homework.

He ended it correctly, totally, the *with success* part is tacit.

Comment: -1 The two words mean the same. The boy completed his homework but half his answers were wrong. The boy finished his homework and all his answers were correct. The 'additional' meaning of *complete* is not always present. In other words, *complete* can be the same as *finish* (a synonym) and it can also be different from *finish* (a different meaning).

Comment: I did not say it was always present, I underlined a tendency. I also say that they are have a very close meaning... it was exagerated on purpose...

Comment: Your answer is unclear as written

Comment: Look the **bold part**

Answer (score 0):

I guess most of the times these terms can be used interchangeably.

However, you cannot "complete" something that does not "support being complete" (e.g. we say "finish" one's class or one's day, but not "complete").

Moreover, "finish" has far more definitions and uses than "complete", as stated many times above.

So, to sum it up, where "complete" is used, we can also use "finish" (even if it renders the sentence less formal), but not the vice versa.
When we complete something, it comes to an end (it finishes).
Nevertheless, when we finish something, it does not necessarily complete.

The same, more or less, meaning of and differences between the two verbs are met in greek as well:
Finish -> Tel-iono: telos -> the end (noun)
and 
Complete -> Oloklir-ono: olokliros -> whole, complete (adj.)

Answer (score 0):

No,there is no real difference between *'finished'* and *'completed'* in the sentence : *"He finished / completed his homework"*.

But sometimes the verb *'finish'* has a negative connotation : the sentence *"She finished my life"* means *'she ruined my life'*. In this context, the verb *'complete'* cannot be used.
Similarly, the verb *'complete'* has a positive connotation : the sentence *"You have completed my life"* may be a Good Night message for wife, meaning *without you, my life is incomplete*.

Answer (score -1):

Complete and finish are opposite in meaning but their use can be made to give the same meaning.

Complete is to be wholly made up.
Finish is to exhaust, or expended.
So in their use in a sentence, they can be used from that opposite direction to convey the same meaning: as in a cup being half filled or half empty.

One can complete his shopping when one has filled the shopping bag with all items to be bought.

One can finish shopping when one has exhausted the items in the shopping list.

Comment: When someone finishes their homework, or a race, they have not *exhausted* those things in any meaningful way. They've completed them. Likewise, one can finish turning a clay vase, which means it's fully formed, or even finish a tabletop by putting the final coat of lacquer or stain on it, which is known as the wood's "finish". It's true that finish sometimes has the sense of running out or running low, but it's much more common for it to simply mean the same thing as complete: that something is done.